# Displaying entire row of max() value from nested table

Tags: sql, oracle, orm, nested, max

My table CUSTOMER_TABLE has a nested table of references toward ACCOUNT_TABLE. Each account in ACCOUNT_TABLE has a reference toward a branch: branch_ref.

```
CREATE TYPE account AS object(
    accid integer,
    acctype varchar2(15),
    balance number,
    rate number,
    overdraft_limit integer,
    branch_ref ref branch,
    opendate date
) final;


CREATE TYPE customer as object(
    custid integer,
    infos ref type_person,
    accounts accounts_list
);


create type branch under elementary_infos(
    bid integer
) final;
```

**All tables are inherited from these object types.**

I want to select the account with the highest balance per branch. I arrived to do that with this query:

```
select MAX(value(a).balance), value(a).branch_ref.bid
from customer_table c, table(c.accounts) a
group by value(a).branch_ref.bid
order by value(a).branch_ref.bid;
```

Which returns:

```
                  MAX(VALUE(A).BALANCE)                 VALUE(A).BRANCH_REF.BID
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                              176318.88                                       0
                              192678.14                                       1
                              190488.19                                       2
                              196433.93                                       3
                              182909.84                                       4
```

However, how to select as well others attribues from the max accounts displayed ? I would like to display the name of the owner plus the customer's id. The id is directly an attribute of customer. But the name is stored with a reference toward person_table. So I have to select as well c.id & deref(c.infos).names.surname.

How to select these other attributes with my MAX() query ?

Thank you

Comment: Guilhem can you please include the DDL for these tables `CUSTOMER_TABLE` and 'ACCOUNT_TABLE'?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use [analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) to achieve that kind of functionality. With analytic functions, you can add aggregate columns to your query without losing the original rows. In your particular case it would be something like:

```
select
  -- select interesting fields
  accid,
  acctype,
  balance,
  rate,
  overdraft_limit,
  branch_ref,
  opendate,
  max_balance
from (
  select 
    -- propagate original fields to outer query
    value(a).accid accid,
    value(a).acctype acctype,
    value(a).balance balance,
    value(a).rate rate,
    value(a).overdraft_limit overdraft_limit,
    value(a).branch_ref branch_ref,
    value(a).opendate opendate,
    -- add max(balance) of our branch_ref to the row
    max(value(a).balance) over (partition by value(a).branch_ref.bid) max_balance
  from customer_table c, table(c.accounts) a
) data
where 
  -- we are only interested in rows with balance equal to the max
  -- (NOTE: there might be more than one, you should fine tune the  filtering!)
  data.balance = data.max_balance
-- order by branch
order by data.branch_ref.bid;
```

I don't have any Oracle instance available right now to test this, but that would be the idea, unless there is some kind of incompatibility between analytic functions and collection columns, you should be able to have that working with little effort.